# How to re-enable lock screen?

Tags: 12.10, lock-screen

Once I disabled the screen lock using a command that I can't remember.

Now I want to re-enable the screen lock (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)  but I don't know how.

If I look at **System Settings** → **Brightness and Lock** the **Lock** switcher is dimmed, how to enable it?

Comment: Which one was it @coanor ??

Comment: @Rinzwind: tag=12.10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Command line you should be able to control this option with...

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'false'
  ```
- This will lock the screen from command line

  ```
  gnome-screensaver-command -l
  ```

  If it says command not found you found your answer: you probably removed gnome-screensaver so the option became invalid. (`sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver` to re-install).