# Unable to lock screen Ubuntu 14.04 fresh installation

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

How I can enable screen lock feature.

The screen in system setting is disabled. So I am not able to enable it.

[image: Lock feature is disabled]

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Problem resolved using - http://askubuntu.com/questions/248323/how-to-re-enable-lock-screen